# Lua - XML Parsing with LuaXML

Tags: xml, parsing, lua, luaxml

I am trying to parse the XML file with [LuaXML](http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/)

```
function customURLtoSteam64(web, sid)
local xml = require("luaXml")
local xfile = xml.load("http://steamcommunity.com/id/GreenMarineValve?xml=1") --line189
local xscene = xfile:find("steamID64[1]") 
return render_front(web, xscene)
end
```

But I get this error:

```
.\index.lua:189: attempt to index local 'xml' (a boolean value)
stack traceback:
.\index.lua:189: in function <.\index.lua:186>
(tail call): ?
(tail call): ?.\index.lua:189: attempt to index local 'xml' (a boolean value)
stack traceback:
c:\Lua\LuaRocks/share/lua/5.1/coxpcall.lua:24: in function 
(tail call): ?
(tail call): ?
c:\Lua\LuaRocks/share/lua/5.1/orbit.lua:540: in function 
(tail call): ?
(tail call): ?
```

I did not understand what is wrong, how can I correctly do that?

Comment: I am using 5.1 version of LuaXML

Comment: In this case use simply `require("luaXml")`, don't assign it to a local.

Comment: It solves if I use "file.xml" but it won't grab from the URL,  LuaXml ERROR: "http://steamcommunity.com/id/GreenMarineValve?xml=1" file error or file not found! What can I do to grab it from there?

Comment: The luaXML manual says that *xml.load(filename)
loads xml data from a file*.

Comment: If you know, can you suggest me a library that can load it from the URL or can you give me advice on how to achieve that? Also, I personally thank you so much @lhf you helped a lot to me.

Comment: I suggest you ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `require` idiom you have used is the one recommended for Lua 5.2. Although the idiom also works for Lua 5.1, most (but not all) libraries for Lua 5.1 usually defined globals and did not return the value they define via `require`. In the absence of a return value from a `luaopen_xxx` function, `require` returns true, hence the error message you've seen.

So, just use simply `require("luaXml")`, don't assign it to a local.